# has_many by boolean value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, include, has-many

In my ruby on rails app i have two models: User and Item

In my user model I would like a relation where a user can have many items like this:

```
has_many :items
```

For the relationship I would not only use the user_id column in the items table.

When I do

```
User.includes(:items)
```

I would rather have all items where
- the items user_id belongs to the user (the classical way)
- or e.g. a boolean column (like all_users) is true

Can this be done with

```
has_many :items + any special options?
```

And how would it look like?

Thanks & Regards, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

`User.includes(:items)` just instructs rails SQL builder to load all *nested* items withing loaded users.

That said,

```
User.includes(:items).all # will load all users with all nested items
User.includes(:items).where(name: 'Joe') # will load user(s) Joe and their items
```

this is done to minimize an amount of queries against the database.

Whether one wants to load all *items*, the query on `Item` should be used, e.g.:

```
Item.where(user_id: User.find_by_name('Joe').pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is to associate an Item to either one or all users without having a many_to_many associaton but a "all_users" checkbox.

Comment: I am not able to read your mind. Btw, this is impossible in relational db without manytomany.